# Missing Authentication Token - AWS API gateway message

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an API gateway get method. I can test it successfully using the test function. It calls a lambda function and returns sucessfully.
However, copying the invoke URL of API gateway function into a broswer, I get the following error message:

```
{"message": "Missing Authentication Token"}
```

1. I created an authorizer for my api gateway
   type is Lambda function
   Token source: method.request.header.Authorization
   Token validation - optional: None
2. I created the authorizer Lambda function as the following code:

```
export const handler = async (event) => {
    const token = event.authorizationToken;

    const policy = {
        principalId: 'user123', // Unique identifier for the user
        policyDocument: {
            Version: '2012-10-17',
            Statement: [
                {
                    Action: 'execute-api:Invoke',
                    Effect: 'Allow',
                    Resource: 'arn:aws:execute-api:eu-north-1:xxx:c8mhri79ja/prod/*/*',
                },
            ],
        },
    };

    return policy;
};
```

3. I set the VPC, subnet an security group as it is set for my other Lambda function I try to call via api gateway.
4. The execution role assigned with the authorizer lambda has AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole policy set
5. If I run test from the API Gateway console, it is executed without errors. SO the gateway and lambda function works correctly.
6. If I add the resource name to the end of the invoke URL, I get the following error message:

```
{"message": "Unauthorized"}
```

why I get the same arror message as I got without setting any Authorizers?
How can I get rid of the error?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for token on the event object directly - `event.authorizationToken` which does not exist.

Authorization token exists on request header so your token is probably there on `event.headers.authorization` or `event.headers.Authorization` ([for older versions of API gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65118977/9145389)).